# Can bash write to its own input stream?

Tags: bash

Is it possible in an interactive **bash** shell to enter a command that outputs some text so that it appears at the next command prompt, as if the user had typed in that text at that prompt ?

I want to be able to `source` a script that will generate a command-line and output it so that it appears when the prompt returns after the script ends so that the user can optionally edit it before pressing `enter` to execute it.

This can be achieved with `xdotool` but that only works when the terminal is in an X window and only if it's installed.

```
[me@mybox] 100 $ xdotool type "ls -l"
[me@mybox] 101 $ ls -l  <--- cursor appears here!
```

**Can this be done using bash only?**

Comment: I'm thinking this should not be hard with Expect, if you can tolerate that, and have it drive a subshell; but I don' remember enough of it to post an actual answer.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

With `zsh`, you can use `print -z` to place some text into the line editor buffer for the next prompt:

```
print -z echo test
```

would prime the line editor with `echo test` which you can edit at the next prompt.

I don't think `bash` has a similar feature, however on many systems, you can prime the terminal device input buffer with the `TIOCSTI` `ioctl()`:

```
perl -e 'require "sys/ioctl.ph"; ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_)
  for split "", join " ", @ARGV' echo test
```

Would insert `echo test` into the terminal device input buffer, as if received from the terminal.

A more portable variation on [@mike's `Terminology` approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213805/22565) and that doesn't sacrifice security would be to send the terminal emulator a fairly standard `query status report` escape sequence: `<ESC>[5n` which terminals invariably reply (so as input) as `<ESC>[0n` and bind that to the string you want to insert:

```
bind '"\e[0n": "echo test"'; printf '\e[5n'
```

If within GNU `screen`, you can also do:

```
screen -X stuff 'echo test'
```

Now, except for the TIOCSTI ioctl approach, we're asking the terminal emulator to send us some string as if typed. If that string comes before `readline` (`bash`'s line editor) has disabled terminal local echo, then that string will be displayed *not* at the shell prompt, messing up the display slightly.

To work around that, you could either delay the sending of the request to the terminal slightly to make sure the response arrives when the echo has been disabled by readline.

```
bind '"\e[0n": "echo test"'; ((sleep 0.05;  printf '\e[5n') &)
```

(here assuming your `sleep` supports sub-second resolution).

Ideally you'd want to do something like:

```
bind '"\e[0n": "echo test"'
stty -echo
printf '\e[5n'
wait-until-the-response-arrives
stty echo
```

However `bash` (contrary to `zsh`) doesn't have support for such a `wait-until-the-response-arrives` that doesn't read the response.

However it has a `has-the-response-arrived-yet` feature with `read -t0`:

```
bind '"\e[0n": "echo test"'
saved_settings=$(stty -g)
stty -echo -icanon min 1 time 0
printf '\e[5n'
until read -t0; do
  sleep 0.02
done
stty "$saved_settings"
```

### Further reading

See [@starfry's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217390)'s that expands on the two solutions given by @mikeserv and myself with a few more detailed information.

Comment: I think `bind '"\e[0n": "echo test"'; printf '\e[5n'` probably the bash-only answer I'm looking for. It works for me. However, I get `^[[0n` printed before my prompt as well. I discovered this is caused when `$PS1` contains a subshell. You can reproduce it by doing `PS1='$(:)'` before the bind command. Why would that happen and can anything be done about it?

Comment: Although everything in this answer is correct, the question was for bash, not zsh.  Sometimes we do not have a choice of what shell to use.

Comment: @Falsenames only the first paragraph is for zsh. The rest is either shell agnostic or bash specific. The Q&A doesn't have to be useful only to bash users.

Comment: @starfry seems like maybe you could just put a `\r`eturn at the head of `$PS1`? That should work if `$PS1` is long enough. If not then put `^[[M` there.

Comment: @mikeserv - `r` does the trick. This doesn't of course prevent the output, it's just overwritten before the eye sees it. I guess `^[[M` erases the line to clear the injected text in case it's longer than the prompt. Is that right (I could't find it in the ANSI escape list I have) ?

Comment: @starfry- Yes - the ^[[M escape should delete the line. Or ^[[K\r should be fine, too.

Comment: @starfry - that will have other consequences though - `readline` isn't very good about prompt positioning. So any time output to the terminal doesn't end w/ a newline, your prompt will overwrite it. Do `printf "where'd this go?"` to see what i mean.

Comment: @stephane-chazelas - your typeahead workaround wrapper is good; it works also when injecting multiple lines and works with `TIOCSTI` too. The `\r\e[M` suggested by @mikeserv is simpler but doesn't work across newlines.

Comment: @starfry - how do you get newlines out of `^[[0n`?

Comment: @mikeserv - I don't. Sorry I was referring to using `\r\e[M` with the `TIOCSTI` method. If I send a command that way (such as `echo test`) and include a newline then the command appears before the prompt because the a new line has been fed and that (empty) line is the only one that `r\e[M` affects. I don't think you can get a newline out of `^[[0n`.

Comment: Actually, @mikeserv, doing `bind '"\e[0n":"ls^M"'` where `^M` is obtained by pressing `CONTROL+V` followed by `CONTROL+M` gives you a newline in the bound string.

Comment: @starfry - yeah, that makes sense. Linux terminals set the `stty sane` mode with `icrnl` - which means they translate input carriage returns to newlines. I t makes sense that readline would obey that in interpreted bound input. Cool trick, too. If you didn't yet notice, a few days ago I updated my own answer here to drop the while loop entirely  and simplify the whole affair a good deal to the point that the `bash` launched gets a  direct write descriptor on its own stdin. Actually, much of the simplification was due to my rereading Stéphane's suggestions while awake enough to understand some.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas @mikeserv Can one somehow extend your solutions to harder task: write a command to the **other** terminal, say `/dev/pts/3`? For simplification, lets say both terminals use the same shell type.

Comment: @jimmij - With super-user permissions on a linux system, or with `reptyr` or similar, or with at least the possibility of first entering a command or two at the other terminal *(such as `while sleep 1; do :; done`)*, then any of them could be made to work. The terminal emulator solutions will just work anyway, though. `printf \\33\[escape_sequence >/dev/pts/[num]` will just work if the reading program interprets the escape. `xterm` can also be told to use a pre-existing pty with `xterm -S`.

Comment: @jimmij - Yes you can write to another terminal. Your question prompted me to post my personal notes resulting from this question and there is an example C program there that does exactly this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Now at the end of my .bashrc: `[[ $TERM == screen* ]] && bind '"\e[0n": "tmux && exit"' && ((sleep 0.05;  printf '\e[5n') &)`

Answer (score 37):

This answer is provided as clarification of my own understanding and is inspired by @StéphaneChazelas and @mikeserv before me.

**TL;DR**

- it isn't possible to do this in `bash` without external help;
- the correct way to do this is with a *send terminal input* `ioctl` but
- the easiest workable `bash` solution uses `bind`.

### The easy solution

> `bind '"\e[0n": "ls -l"'; printf '\e[5n'`

Bash has a shell builtin called `bind` that allows a shell command to be executed when a key sequence is received. In essence, the output of the shell command is written to the shell's input buffer.

```
$ bind '"\e[0n": "ls -l"'
```

The key sequence `\e[0n` (`<ESC>[0n`) is an [ANSI Terminal escape code](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) that a terminal sends to indicate that it is functioning normally. It sends this in response to a *device status report request* which is sent as `<ESC>[5n`.

By binding the response to an `echo` that outputs the text to inject, we can inject that text whenever we want by requesting device status and that's done by sending a `<ESC>[5n` escape sequence.

```
printf '\e[5n'
```

This works, and is probably sufficient to answer the original question because no other tools are involved. It's pure `bash` but relies on a well-behaving terminal (practically all are).

It leaves the echoed text on the command line ready to be used as if it had been typed. It can be appended, edited, and pressing `ENTER` causes it to be executed.

Add `\n` to the bound command to have it executed automatically.

However, this solution only works in the current terminal (which is within the scope of the original question). It works from an interactive prompt or from a *sourced* script but it raises an error if used from a subshell:

```
bind: warning: line editing not enabled
```

*The correct solution* described next is more flexible but it relies on external commands.

### The correct solution

The proper way to inject input uses [tty_ioctl](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl), a unix system call for *I/O Control* that has a `TIOCSTI` command that can be used to inject input.

***TIOC*** from "***T**erminal **IOC**tl*" and ***STI*** from "***S**end **T**erminal **I**nput*".

There is no command built into `bash` for this; doing so requires an external command. There isn't such a command in the typical GNU/Linux distribution but it isn't difficult to achieve with a little programming. Here's a shell function that uses `perl`:

```
function inject() {
  perl -e 'ioctl(STDIN, 0x5412, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV' "$@"
}
```

Here, `0x5412` is the code for the `TIOCSTI` command.

`TIOCSTI` is a constant defined in the standard C header files with the value `0x5412`. Try `grep -r TIOCSTI /usr/include`, or look in `/usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h`; it's included in C programs indirectly by `#include <sys/ioctl.h>`.

You can then do:

```
$ inject ls -l
ls -l$ ls -l <- cursor here
```

Implementations in some other languages are shown below (save in a file and then `chmod +x` it):

**Perl** `inject.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
ioctl(STDIN, 0x5412, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV
```

You can generate `sys/ioctl.ph` which defines `TIOCSTI` instead of using the numeric value. See [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1542693#p1542693)

**Python** `inject.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fcntl, sys, termios
del sys.argv[0]
for c in ' '.join(sys.argv):
  fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdin, termios.TIOCSTI, c)
```

**Ruby** `inject.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
ARGV.join(' ').split('').each { |c| $stdin.ioctl(0x5412,c) }
```

**C** `inject.c`

compile with `gcc -o inject inject.c`

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a,c;
  for (a=1, c=0; a< argc; c=0 )
    {
      while (argv[a][c])
        ioctl(0, TIOCSTI, &argv[a][c++]);
      if (++a < argc) ioctl(0, TIOCSTI," ");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

**!**There are further examples [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Simulate_input/Keyboard).

Using `ioctl` to do this works in subshells. It can also inject into other terminals as explained next.

### Taking it further (controlling other terminals)

It's beyond the scope of the original question but it is possible to inject characters into another terminal, subject to having the appropriate permissions. Normally this means being `root`, but see below for other ways.

Extending the C program given above to accept a command-line argument specifying another terminal's tty allows injecting to that terminal:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <argp.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

const char *argp_program_version ="inject - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213799";
static char doc[] = "inject - write to terminal input stream";
static struct argp_option options[] = {
  { "tty",  't', "TTY", 0, "target tty (defaults to current)"},
  { "nonl", 'n', 0,     0, "do not output the trailing newline"},
  { 0 }
};

struct arguments
{
  int fd, nl, next;
};

static error_t parse_opt(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state) {
    struct arguments *arguments = state->input;
    switch (key)
      {
        case 't': arguments->fd = open(arg, O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
                  if (arguments->fd > 0)
                    break;
                  else
                    return EINVAL;
        case 'n': arguments->nl = 0; break;
        case ARGP_KEY_ARGS: arguments->next = state->next; return 0;
        default: return ARGP_ERR_UNKNOWN;
      }
    return 0;
}

static struct argp argp = { options, parse_opt, 0, doc };
static struct arguments arguments;

static void inject(char c)
{
  ioctl(arguments.fd, TIOCSTI, &c);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  arguments.fd=0;
  arguments.nl='\n';
  if (argp_parse (&argp, argc, argv, 0, 0, &arguments))
    {
      perror("Error");
      exit(errno);
    }

  int a,c;
  for (a=arguments.next, c=0; a< argc; c=0 )
    {
      while (argv[a][c])
        inject (argv[a][c++]);
      if (++a < argc) inject(' ');
    }
  if (arguments.nl) inject(arguments.nl);

  return 0;
}
```

It also sends a newline by default but, similar to `echo`, it provides a `-n` option to suppress it. The `--t` or `--tty` option requires an argument - the `tty` of the terminal to be injected. The value for this can be obtained in that terminal:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/20
```

Compile it with `gcc -o inject inject.c`. Prefix the text to inject with `--` if it contains any hyphens to prevent the argument parser misinterpreting command-line options. See `./inject --help`. Use it like this:

```
$ inject --tty /dev/pts/22 -- ls -lrt
```

or just

```
$ inject  -- ls -lrt
```

to inject the current terminal.

Injecting into another terminal requires administrative rights that can be obtained by:

- issuing the command as `root`,
- using `sudo`,
- having the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability or
- setting the executable `setuid`

To assign `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`:

```
$  sudo setcap cap_sys_admin+ep inject
```

To assign `setuid`:

```
$ sudo chown root:root inject
$ sudo chmod u+s inject
```

### Clean output

Injected text appears ahead of the prompt as if it was typed before the prompt appeared (which, in effect, it was) but it then appears again after the prompt.

One way to hide the text that appears ahead of the prompt is to prepend the prompt with a carriage return (`\r` not line-feed) and clear the current line (`<ESC>[M`):

```
$ PS1="\r\e[M$PS1"
```

However, this will only clear the line on which the prompt appears. If the injected text includes newlines then this won't work as intended.

Another solution disables echoing of injected characters. A wrapper uses `stty` to do this:

```
saved_settings=$(stty -g)
stty -echo -icanon min 1 time 0
inject echo line one
inject echo line two
until read -t0; do
  sleep 0.02
done
stty "$saved_settings"
```

where `inject` is one of the solutions described above, or replaced by `printf '\e[5n'`.

### Alternative approaches

If your environment meets certain prerequisites then you may have other methods available that you can use to inject input. If you're in a desktop environment then [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool) is an [X.Org](http://www.x.org) utility that simulates mouse and keyboard activity but your distro may not include it by default. You can try:

```
$ xdotool type ls
```

If you use [tmux](http://tmux.github.io), the terminal multiplexer, then you can do this:

```
$ tmux send-key -t session:pane ls
```

where `-t` selects which *session* and *pane* to inject. [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) has a similar capability with its `stuff` command:

```
$ screen -S session -p pane -X stuff ls
```

If your distro includes the [console-tools](http://lct.sourceforge.net) package then you may have a `writevt` command that uses `ioctl` like our examples. Most distros have, however, deprecated this package in favour of [kbd](http://www.kbd-project.org) which lacks this feature.

An updated copy of [writevt.c](https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/master/thirdparty/writevt.c) can be compiled using `gcc -o writevt writevt.c`.

Other options that may fit some use-cases better include [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net) and [empty](http://empty.sourceforge.net) which are designed to allow interactive tools to be scripted.

You could also use a shell that supports terminal injection such as `zsh` which can do `print -z ls`.

### The "Wow, that's clever..." answer

The method described here is also discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213805) and builds on the method discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179030).

A shell redirect from `/dev/ptmx` gets a new pseudo-terminal:

```
$ $ ls /dev/pts; ls /dev/pts </dev/ptmx
0  1  2  ptmx
0  1  2  3  ptmx
```

A little tool written in C that unlocks the pseudoterminal master (ptm) and outputs the name of the pseudoterminal slave (pts) to its standard output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(unlockpt(0)) return 2;
    char *ptsname(int fd);
    printf("%s\n",ptsname(0));
    return argc - 1;
}
```

(save as `pts.c` and compile with `gcc -o pts pts.c`)

When the program is called with its standard input set to a ptm it unlocks the corresponding pts and outputs its name to standard output.

```
$ ./pts </dev/ptmx
/dev/pts/20
```

- The [unlockpt()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/unlockpt)  function  unlocks  the  slave  pseudoterminal  device corresponding to the master pseudoterminal referred to by the given file descriptor. The program passes this as zero which is the program's *standard input*.
- The [ptsname()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ptsname)  function  returns  the name of the slave pseudoterminal device corresponding to the master referred to by the given file descriptor, again passing zero for the program's standard input.

A process can be connected to the pts. First get a ptm (here it's assigned to file descriptor 3, opened read-write by the `<>` redirect).

```
 exec 3<>/dev/ptmx
```

Then start the process:

```
$ (setsid -c bash -i 2>&1 | tee log) <>"$(./pts <&3)" 3>&- >&0 &
```

The processes spawned by this command-line is best illustrated with `pstree`:

```
$ pstree -pg -H $(jobs -p %+) $$
bash(5203,5203)─┬─bash(6524,6524)─┬─bash(6527,6527)
            │                 └─tee(6528,6524)
            └─pstree(6815,6815)
```

The output is relative to the current shell (`$$`) and the PID (`-p`) and PGID (`-g`) of each process are shown in parentheses `(PID,PGID)`.

At the head of the tree is `bash(5203,5203)`, the interactive shell that we're typing commands into, and its file descriptors connect it to the terminal application we're using to interact with it (`xterm`, or similar).

```
$ ls -l /dev/fd/
lrwx------ 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 2 -> /dev/pts/3
```

Looking at the command again, the first set of parentheses started a subshell, `bash(6524,6524)`) with its file descriptor 0 (its *standard input*) being assigned to the pts (which is opened read-write, `<>`) as returned by another subshell that executed `./pts <&3` to unlock the pts associated with file descriptor 3 (created in the preceding step, `exec 3<>/dev/ptmx`).

The subshell's file descriptor 3 is closed (`3>&-`) so that the ptm isn't accessible to it. Its standard input (fd 0), which is the pts that was opened read/write, is redirected (actually the fd is copied - `>&0`) to its standard output (fd 1).

This creates a subshell with its standard input and output connected to the pts. It can be sent input by writing to the ptm and its output can be seen by reading from the ptm:

```
$ echo 'some input' >&3 # write to subshell
$ cat <&3               # read from subshell
```

The subshell executes this command:

```
setsid -c bash -i 2>&1 | tee log
```

It runs `bash(6527,6527)` in interactive (`-i`) mode in a new session (`setsid -c`, note the PID and PGID are the same). Its standard error is redirected to its standard output (`2>&1`) and piped via `tee(6528,6524)` so it's written to a `log` file as well as to the pts. This gives another way to see the subshell's output:

```
$ tail -f log
```

Because the subshell is running `bash` interactively, it can be sent commands to execute, like this example which displays the subshell's file descriptors:

```
$ echo 'ls -l /dev/fd/' >&3
```

Reading subshell's output (`tail -f log` or `cat <&3`) reveals:

```
lrwx------ 0 -> /dev/pts/17
l-wx------ 1 -> pipe:[116261]
l-wx------ 2 -> pipe:[116261]
```

Standard input (fd 0) is connected to the pts and both standard output (fd 1) and error (fd 2) are connected to the same pipe, the one that connects to `tee`:

```
$ (find /proc -type l | xargs ls -l | fgrep 'pipe:[116261]') 2>/dev/null
l-wx------ /proc/6527/fd/1 -> pipe:[116261]
l-wx------ /proc/6527/fd/2 -> pipe:[116261]
lr-x------ /proc/6528/fd/0 -> pipe:[116261]
```

And a look at the file descriptors of `tee`

```
$ ls -l /proc/6528/fd/
lr-x------ 0 -> pipe:[116261]
lrwx------ 1 -> /dev/pts/17
lrwx------ 2 -> /dev/pts/3
l-wx------ 3 -> /home/myuser/work/log
```

Standard Output (fd 1) is the pts: anything that 'tee' writes to its standard output is sent back to the ptm. Standard Error (fd 2) is the pts belonging to the controlling terminal.

**Wrapping it up**

The following script uses the technique described above. It sets up an interactive `bash` session that can be injected by writing to a file descriptor. It's available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnlane/random-toolbox/master/examples/bash-injectable) and documented with explanations.

```
sh -cm 'cat <&9 &cat >&9|(             ### copy to/from host/slave
        trap "  stty $(stty -g         ### save/restore stty settings on exit
                stty -echo raw)        ### host: no echo and raw-mode
                kill -1 0" EXIT        ### send a -HUP to host pgrp on EXIT
        <>"$($pts <&9)" >&0 2>&1\
        setsid -wc -- bash) <&1        ### point bash <0,1,2> at slave and setsid bash
' --    9<>/dev/ptmx 2>/dev/null       ### open pty master on <>9
```

Comment: With the easiest `bind '"\e[0n": "ls -l"'; printf '\e[5n'` solution, after all the output of the `ls -l` also `^[[0n` will be outputted on the Terminal once I hit the enter key thus run `ls -l`. Any ideas how to "hide" it please? Thank you.

Comment: I presented one solution that gives the effect you are after - in the _clean output_ section of my answer I suggest adding a return to the prompt to hide surpflouous text. I tried `PS1="\r\e[M$PS1"` before doing `bind '"\e[0n": "ls -l"'; printf '\e[5n'` and that gave the effect you describe.

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed that point.

Comment: As of Linux 6.2, TIOCSTI is disabled by default: https://lore.kernel.org/linux-hardening/20221015041626.1467372-2-keescook@chromium.org/

Answer (score 20):

It depends on what you mean by *`bash` only*. If you mean a single, interactive `bash` session, then the answer is almost definitely **no**. And this is because even when you enter a command like `ls -l` at the command-line on any canonical terminal then `bash` is not yet even aware of it - and `bash` isn't even involved at that point.

Rather, what has happened up to that point is that the kernel's tty line-discipline has buffered and `stty echo`d the user's input only to the screen. It flushes that input to its reader  - `bash`, in your example case - line by line - and generally translates `\r`eturns to `\n`ewlines on Unix systems as well - and so `bash` isn't - and so neither can your sourced script be - made aware there is any input at all until the user presses the *`ENTER`* key.

Now, there are some work-arounds. The most robust is not a work-around at all, actually, and involves using multiple processes or specially-written programs to sequence input, hide the line-discipline's `-echo` from the user, and only write to the screen what is judged appropriate while interpreting input specially when necessary. This can be difficult to do well because it means writing interpretation rules which can handle arbitrary input char by char as it arrives and to write it out simultaneously without mistake in order to simulate what the average user would expect in that scenario. It is for this reason, probably, that interactive terminal i/o is so rarely well understood - a prospect that difficult is not one which lends itself to further investigation for most.

Another work-around could involve the terminal emulator. You say that a problem for you is a dependency on X and on `xdotool`. In that case such a work-around as I'm about to offer might have similar issues, but I'll go forward with it just the same.

```
printf  '\33[22;1t\33]1;%b\33\\\33[20t\33[23;0t' \
        '\025my command'
```

That will work in an `xterm` w/ the *`allowwindowOps`* resource set. It first saves the icon/window names on a stack, then sets the terminal's icon-string to *`^Umy command`* then requests that the terminal inject that name into the input queue, and last resets it to the saved values. It should work invisibly for interactive `bash` shells run in an `xterm`  w/ the right config- but it's probably a bad idea. Please see Stéphane's comments below.

Here, though, is a picture I took of my Terminology terminal after running the `printf` bit w/ a different escape sequence on my machine. For each newline in the `printf` command I typed *`CTRL+V`* then *`CTRL+J`* and afterward pressed the *`ENTER`* key. I typed nothing afterward, but, as you can see, the terminal injected *`my command`* into the line-discipline's input queue for me:

[image: term_inject]

The real way to do this is w/ a nested pty. It is how `screen` and `tmux` and similar work - both of which, by the way, can make this possible for you. `xterm` actually comes with a little program called `luit` which can also make this possible. It is not easy, though.

Here's one way you might:

```
sh -cm 'cat <&9 &cat >&9|(             ### copy to/from host/slave
        trap "  stty $(stty -g         ### save/restore stty settings on exit
                stty -echo raw)        ### host: no echo and raw-mode
                kill -1 0" EXIT        ### send a -HUP to host pgrp on EXIT
        <>"$(pts <&9)" >&0 2>&1\       
        setsid -wc -- bash) <&1        ### point bash <0,1,2> at slave and setsid bash
' --    9<>/dev/ptmx 2>/dev/null       ### open pty master on <>9
```

That is by no means portable, but should work on most Linux systems given proper permissions for opening `/dev/ptmx`. My user is in the *`tty`* group which is enough on my system. You'll also need...

```
<<\C cc -xc - -o pts
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if(unlockpt(0)) return 2;
        char *ptsname(int fd);
        printf("%s\n",ptsname(0));
        return argc - 1;
}
C
```

...which, when run on a GNU system *(or any other with a standard C compiler that can also read from stdin)*, will write out a small executable binary named `pts` that will run the `unlockpt()` function on its stdin and write to its stdout the name of the pty device it just unlocked. I wrote it when working on... [How do I come by this pty and what can I do with it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179151/52934).

Anyway, what the above bit of code does is runs a `bash` shell in a pty a layer beneath the current tty. `bash` is told to write all output to the slave pty, and the current tty is configured both not to `-echo` its input nor to buffer it, but instead to pass it *(mostly)* `raw` to `cat`, which copies it over to `bash`. And all the while another, backgrounded `cat` copies all slave output to the current tty.

For the most part the above configuration would be entirely useless - just redundant, basically - *except* that we launch `bash` with a copy of its own pty master fd on `<>9`. This means that `bash` can freely write to its own input stream with a simple redirection. All that `bash` has to do is:

```
echo echo hey >&9
```

...to talk to itself.

Here's another picture:

[image]

Comment: What terminals did you manage to get that working in? That kind of thing was being abused in the olden days and should be disabled by default nowadays. With `xterm`, you can still query the icon title with `\e[20t` but only if configured with `allowWindowOps: true`.

Comment: That's [CVE-2003-0063](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2003-0063)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that works in Terminology, but i'm pretty sure it also works in gnome terminal, in the kde terminal *(i forget its name, and i think there's a different escape)*, and as you say, w/ `xterm` w/ the proper config. W/ an xterm proper, though, you can read and write the copy/paste buffer and so it gets more simple besides, I think. Xterm also has escape sequences for changing/affecting the term description itself.

Comment: I can't get that to work in anything but terminology (which btw has several other similar vulnerabilities). That CVE being over 12 years old and relatively well known I'd be surprised if any of the main terminal emulator had the same vulnerability. Note that with xterm, that's `\e[20t` (not `\e]1;?\a`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - that's really good news - that's always worried me. i only pulled the information at all from theinivisbleisland.net list of escapes for xterm - it's definitely documented there for OSC. It also reports that an xterm will respond to ENQ w/ the string saved in its *`answerbackString`* resource - so that could work as another route. I should probably edit this and just tell the right way to do it - with a pty.

Comment: [The `?` to query is only for font and color there](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Controls), not titles

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I found the 20t escape you mentioned. Thank you. And copy/paste buffer thing only works for xterms w/ allowwindowOp resources enabled as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - if you get this, will you look at my edit and maybe bestow some wisdom about the job control error?

Comment: You'll want to also set stdout and stderr to that slave (and relay to the host tty). and do a stty raw -echo on the host (no isig no opost...)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - thanks, but maybe I'm a little slow cause I'm sleepy - would you mind expanding on that a little? If I set stdout+err >&8 then how do I get the output on screen? I suspected the isig had to do with the job control thing... Another thing which bugging me is the winch stuff doesn't work - I can query the host's rows/cols with `stty -aF"$TTY"` in the slave session, but no `trap` seems effective on either side - slave or host. There must be a way to capture that signal... maybe backgrounding `cat` and using `wait`...

Comment: You'll need another relaying `cat <&9`. For winch, either the shell has its own handler and your trap will be ignored or it hasn't and COLS/LINES won't be updated.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - about COLS/LINES - i had tried giving up on those shell vars and did a thing like `trap 'stty -aF"$TTY"|{ IFS=\; read n r c n; IFS=\ ;stty $r $c </dev/tty; }' WINCH` in the slave session. It works - if I do `kill -WINCH -0` myself, but it just doesn't catch it automatically. I did do `trap 'kill -WINCH "$!"' WINCH` in the host session, too. I'll try the `cat` thing now. I didn't do that because I thought it would eat the slave's input. But I guess the master get's its own copy, too, huh?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - well, I did do the >&8 2>&8, and I did stty raw, but I also redirected the slave's stdout+err back at the host with an echo'd exec and kept opost. The winch thing? Probably I'll figure it out later. I did the redirect because the prompts weren't coming through on <&9 for bash - readline is weird. Anyway, all of the slaves isig controls work - and rearranged execution order to make an `exit` in the slave break up the whole affair. It's pretty good. It was fun to do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mikeserv I was trying to digest your answer. Could you explain the escape sequences in your `printf`? I looked at [this doc](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) which is probably the right haystack but the needle eludes me :)

Comment: @starfry - yeah, it's hard at first. `\33[` is the 7-bit equivalent for *CSI* *(there is a single, 8-bit character for it too, but `\33[` is what I use)*. That's the biggest hurdle, really. *OSC* is `\33]` - so all of the escapes here start w/ 1 or the other, and end w/ \33\ - the *string terminator*. `\25` is ^U - which erases all of the terminal junk at the head of the line. So we save `OSC 1;^Umy command ST` to *icon_name*, then `?` query it, then reset it. The `xterm` bit is similar, but `xterm` provides a stack. Anyway, you should be looking at the pty stuff. The script is pretty good.

Comment: @mikserv I have been pulling my hair out trying to understand the script but I have it now thanks to your linked answer and a bit of experimentation. I guess this could be used to wrap more complex things such as a chroot or other container.  Why the `--` - are they needed? it seems to work without them. Explaining this would make a good interview question (or perhaps that's just too mean :))

Comment: @starfry - no, `--` really aren't needed. But *(one of)* my own version[s] is a little more complicated, and i don't do `setsid -wc bash` but rather `setsid -wc -- "$@"` and use the `sh -c '...' -- my list of arbitrary arguments that need executing` to easily pass in arbitrary execution statements without fretting over quote worries. In that case if arg1 happens to begin with a `-` there's no need to worry, even if such a thing is incredibly unlikely anyway. About the interview thing - I sure could use one those, but no idea where to start...

Answer (score 8):

Though the `ioctl(,TIOCSTI,)` [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213821/119298)
by Stéphane Chazelas is, of course, the right answer, some people might be happy enough with this partial but trivial answer:  simply push the command onto the history stack, then the user can move 1 line up the history to find the command.

```
$ history -s "ls -l"
$ echo "move up 1 line in history to get command to run"
```

This can become a simple script, which has its own 1 line history:

```
#!/bin/bash
history -s "ls -l"
read -e -p "move up 1 line: "
eval "$REPLY"
```

`read -e` enables readline editing of the input, `-p` is a prompt.

Comment: That will only work in shell functions, or if the script was sourced (`. foo.sh` or `source foo.sh, instead of run in a subshell.)  Interesting approach, though.  A similar hack that requires modifying the context of the calling shell would be to set up a custom completion that expanded the empty line to something, and then restored the old completion handler.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are right. I was taking the question too literally. But I've added an example of a simple script that could work.

Comment: @mikeserv Hey, its just a simple solution that may be useful to some people. You can even remove the `eval` if you have simple commands to edit, without pipes and redirection etc.

Answer (score 3):

Oh my word, we missed **a simple solution built-in to bash**:
the `read` command has an option `-i ...`, which when used with `-e`, pushes text into the input buffer.
From the man page:

> **-i** *text*
>
> > If  readline  is  being  used  to  read the line, text is
> >       placed into the editing buffer before editing begins.

So create a small bash function or shell script which takes
the command to present to the user, and runs or evaluates their reply:

```
domycmd(){ read -e -i "$*"; eval "$REPLY"; }
```

This no doubt uses the ioctl(,TIOCSTI,) which has been around for over 32 years,
as it already existed
in [2.9BSD ioctl.h](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=2.9BSD/usr/include/sys/ioctl.h).

Comment: Interesting one with a similar effect, but it doesn't inject to the prompt though.

Comment: on 2nd thoughts you are right. bash doesnt need to TIOCSTI since it's doing all the i/o itself.