# Running a command on different shells

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh

While reading the answers of question [Can bash write to its own input stream?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213799/can-bash-write-to-its-own-input-stream?newsletter=1&nlcode=468662%7c561f), I found the following command runs on `zsh` but not on `bash` :

```
print -z echo mnciitbhu
```

1 . Is `-z` an extension to the `print` command? If yes, how do I define my own extensions?

2 . If not, why is the above command not running in `bash` but running in `zsh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In zsh, `print` is a [built-in command](http://bolyai.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_17.html). (And, in bash, `printf` is a [built-in](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) command.) The command, `/usr/bin/print`, is used to run mailcap programs.
The `-z` switch is defined this way from the zsh manual:

> Push the arguments onto the editing buffer stack, separated by spaces; no escape sequences are recognized.