# Change dir from script without a "shell procedure" or "sourcing the script"

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

I know what I can make a [shell procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7020787/1858327) or [source the script instead of running it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2236614/1858327) to `cd` the shell I am using. What I want to know is there *any* way to `cd` the "parent shell" (not sure if that is the correct phrase).

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is script.sh
cd $1
pwd
```

Here's some output. (**Note:** this isn't the exact output, I just shortened it by stripping out unnecessary details. Lines that are my input into the shell begin with `>`.)

```
> mkdir foo
> ./script.sh foo
/home/myName/foo
> pwd
/home/myName
```

This is expected behavior as I understand. Here is if I "source" the script.

```
> . ./script.sh foo
/home/myName/foo
> pwd
/home/myName/foo
```

Without sourcing the script and without making this a shell procedure, is there any way to type `./script.sh foo` result in the shell I am using be in the directory `/home/myName/foo`?

Comment: Why/how are you getting the `> `  `$PS2` prompt there? In any case, no. You cannot change the parent's current working directory from the child context, and the parent calls a child shell to read the script. When you source the script instead the parent reads it rather than calling the child and so changes its own directory. If you want the parent to CD in response to some message or signal from the child you'll have to construct the format yourself.

Comment: @mikeserv I just shortened the output, that's not a straight copy and paste. I will make a note in the question in case it's relevant. Also, what do you mean by "construct the format yourself"? I'm pretty inexperienced with bash and not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Basically you'll need to talk between the processes with a pipe or `kill` signal or whatever. So you'll need some to construct some means of passing information to and from and the protocol is all yours to develop. Its doable, but its not *done*.

Comment: @mikeserv That sounds pretty involved. Wouldn't that mean making a custom bash that could handle this protocol making the script not portable?

Comment: not as such..  Just reading, writing, and testing value of strings written/read. there is an example already posted, in fact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because when you invoke a script as `./script.sh foo`, it starts a subshell to run the script in for you. When that subshell exits, you're placed back in to the directory you were in when you started that script. You can counterfeit this behavior, though, by using a script that does something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
bash
```

This will put you into a subshell after changing directories, which you then have to `exit` to get back to your original shell.

If you instead make the last line:

```
exec bash
```

You will not have to exit the new shell, because the new shell will replace the old shell. Doing this does, however, remain an ugly hack (IMHO).

Comment: Somehow this works... Weird. I'd really rather not have to do an `exit` everytime after I run this. (Note: I didn't downvote)

Comment: Change it to `exec bash`

Comment: Is there a way to make this shell agnostic?

Comment: @Captain Man: instead of `bash` use `$SHELL`. Btw the problem with this solution is that it spawn a subshell every time the script is executed, so you may end up wasting a lot of memory.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no - that's impossible.

But, if you are desperate, you may find some workarounds.

The easiest approach is when there are only a few directories which you *know in advance* (in the parent shell) that the script may try to `cd` into. In such case you can set a trap for some signals which would be send from the script.

```
~ $ cat script
#!/bin/bash
kill -s SIGINT "$PPID"

~ $ trap 'cd /tmp' SIGINT
~ $ ./script
/tmp $
```

A somehow more sophisticated way of doing this is to write the command from the script on the parent shell standard input. The procedure (quite complicated) is described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213799/80886), but the simplest case (with defined directory in advance) is again quite easy:

```
~ $ cat script
#!/bin/bash
printf '\e[5n' >/proc/"$PPID"/fd/0

~ $ bind '"\e[0n": "cd /tmp\n"'
~ $ ./script
/tmp $
```

If you want to pass a directory name as a parameter from the script to parent shell I suggest to study answers from above link.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
gdb --batch -ex 'call chdir("/some/dir")' -p "$PPID"
```

But I'd expect most shells to get confused when their current directory changes under their feet.

By the way, in shell syntax, you need quotes around variables and `--` to separate options from arguments. See also the special behaviour of `cd` when not passed `-P`. So your code should be more like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
cd -P -- "$1"
```

To be equivalent to `int main(int argc, char*argv[]){chdir(argv[1])}` in C for instance (would still be ineffective at changing the current directory of another process)

Answer (score 0):

A script is run in a subshell, any environment changes (directory and variables) are local to that process, and revert to the calling process' ones when the process exits (or otherwise hands control back).

You can run commands *in the current shell* (so their effect stays) via sourcing the script (`. here/is/the/script`) or by defining a shell function. Shell functions can be quite complex, and, crucially, are executed in the current shell process. Not all shells support functions (bash does).

Comment: I literally asked how to do this *without* shell functions and sourcing the script, I even gave an example in my question showing that it works if I source the script.

Comment: @CaptainMan, then the answer is just a resounding ***no***. The rest of the answer is for the benefit of those who want alternatives.