# xdotool type and stty occasionally cut off first letter of input

Tags: terminal, xdotool

I defined a simple function `prepend` (below) that should automatically place a repeated term of a bash command in the following input prompts. For example, by typing `prepend git` in the terminal, all following inputs should have `git` already entered. For the most part, `prepend` does this; however, seemingly at random, `prepend` will cut off the first letter of the word (e.g. `$prepend sensors` yields `$ensors` on the following input prompt).

I was wondering why this is happening and how to possibly fix it. However, if there's an alternative/canonical way to have text entered into input prompts, I wouldn't mind implementing this differently.

```
#!/bin/bash

#stty to stop text from being displayed before $PS1

function prepend {
    if ! [ -z "$1" ]
        then
            PROMPT_COMMAND="stty -echo && xdotool type $1 && stty echo"
            set PROMPT_COMMAND
    else
        unset PROMPT_COMMAND
    fi
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a proper solution, however, your hack is quite fragile. E.g. if you have another window (let's say a browser) focused when a terminal command completes, you'll end up "typing" into that window. On a side note: the "set" command doesn't do what you think it does. For your actual problem: you might inject a few "sleep 0.1"s into PROMPT_COMMAND and see if that helps, I have no clue why the first letter could be swallowed.

Comment: @egmont Thank you. Beyond the window focus, are there other major use-cases I should consider to make the function more robust?

Comment: Use the ioctl `TIOCSTI` to stuff data into the input. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213799/119298).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the first letter is cut off when the key for that character is already held down.  To see this in effect, you can run the following command in your terminal:

```
$ xdotool type foof
```

If you release the `f` key before pressing `Return`, this will print `foof`, but it you hold down the final `f` while pressing `Return` it will print `oof`.  I believe that this occurs becasue xdotool is sending `keydown` events, which don't have any effect when the key is already down.

You can work around this issue by manually sending a `keyup` event:

```
$ xdotool keyup f type foof
```

will always print `foof` correctly.

In your case, this will be slightly more complicated; you'll need to detect the first chararacter of the string to send the correct `keyup`.  But, once you have done so, this approch should work for you as well.