# type string as if it were a keyboard

Tags: devices, unicode, keyboard-event, emulation

I have a bunch of unicode symbols in a file and a script to select and copy one of them [(dmenuunicode script in this repository which I've forked)](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/voidrice). But instead pasting them I would like to save one key press and type them automatically to gui application, I am currently working in.

In order to do that I need some way to type unicode string as if keyboard did that. Ideally I want it to be independent from `xorg` and `wayland` since I frequently switch between them.

The closest thing to what I want I managed to get when writing stuff to `/dev/input/by-path/...` but there are only events, and not unicode symbols.

How can I simulate typing unicode symbols independently from `xorg` and `wayland`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can bash write to its own input stream?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213799/can-bash-write-to-its-own-input-stream)

Comment: No, I need to type symbols to any application, not just terminal

Comment: So the required solution _isn't_ independent of xorg and wayland? You said it was, so I found you a solution that didn't require them.