# In WSL console, how do you read and write to the clipboard?

Tags: windows, clipboard, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do you access the (windows) clipboard in WSL so that you can pipe it into commands, use it as stdin, etc.?

There's more than enough answers about how to *write* to the clipboard. But I couldn't find any specifically about *reading* from it.

For what it's worth: I'm answering my own question. Hopefully this saves others time in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
alias pbpaste="powershell.exe -noprofile Get-Clipboard"
alias pbcopy="clip.exe"
```

You can put something like that in your `.bashrc` file or run the commands directly.

---

I learned the answer from this **question**: [Linux clipboards, including with WSL consoles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673032/linux-clipboards-including-with-wsl-consoles) But, it is not asking the same thing and after 10 minutes of googling, I still can't find a direct answer to my question.